# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to, on the click of a button, complete a to-do item, therefore removing it from the list.

I'm using an ActionLink for the button:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li class="@item.Priority">
      @item.Text
      <div class="agile-detail">
         @Html.ActionLink("Done", "Complete", "Home", new { id = item.ToDoId }, new { @class = "pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary" })
         <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @item.Date
      </div>
   </li>
}
```

And a very short action for the processing in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int todoId)
        {
            using (var db = new KnightOwlContext())
            {
                DashboardHelper dashboardHelper = new DashboardHelper(db);

                dashboardHelper.CompleteToDo(todoId);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Clicking the button generated a URL of:

> http://site/Home/Complete/1

I've looked up a solution and so far it looks like it could be any number of issues. Also the ActionLink button is inside a partial view so I'm not sure if that changes anything in terms of incorrect routing setup? For routing too I'm just using the default config that comes with an MVC project in Visual Studio.

Just having trouble narrowing down the cause of the issue so where to check first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in your method is `int todoId` but you not passing any value for that - your only passing a value for a parameter named `id`.

Change the method to

```
public ActionResult Complete(int id)
```

or change the link to use `new { todoId = item.ToDoId }`, but that will add a query string value, not a route value, unless you create a specific route definition with `url: "Home/Complete/{todoId}"`